# What can I use instead of 'NOT LIKE' in Oracle/PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to improve performance of a query. When I use "like" or "not like", performance reduces.

```
SELECT id FROM Example_Table e WHERE e.Example_Column NOT LIKE 'A%'
```

What can be used instead of "like" or "not like" for improve to performance?

Comment: Are you sure this is causing poor performance?

Comment: Show us table and index definitions, and the explain/execution plan.

Comment: Yes, we found that using too many "like" "not like","or" operators causes slowness in the project. So, I am looking for alternative uses for these operators.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share it because it's company data. But the column I use "not like" has an index.

Comment: when you say 'performance reduces', that is compared to what?

Comment: maybe a regular expression is faster

Answer (score 1):

`NOT LIKE` is probably the solution you want and can use an index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX example_table__id__example_column__idx
  ON example_table (id, example_column);
```

---

However, you can try comparing against the first character (and using a function-based index):

```sql
CREATE INDEX example_table__id__example_column__fidx
  ON example_table (id, SUBSTR(example_column, 1, 1));
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   Example_Table
WHERE  SUBSTR(Example_Column, 1, 1) != 'A'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b8G-a6Ql)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the regexp_like function.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

That may be used in PL/SQL, not only in SQL.
Still, regexp_like is more complex and would lead to poor performance in your SQL, because what you gave there is SQL and not PL/SQL. The plain like is the best for that purpose. regexp_like or substr would perform even worse.
How many rows have you got in that table?
Maybe the parallel hint might help, but that depends on how many processors are available.